# "attached scsi removable disk" stucks at dual boot ubuntu

Tags: operating-system, ubuntu-20.04

Recently i have bought intel i5 13500k and MSI B760M-P DDR4 motherboard. I have successfully installed windows 11, but when i tried to install ubuntu 20.04 LTS from my flash drive, "attached scsi removable disk" this message stucks. How to solve it?

Tried to install ubuntu 20.04 and stucks at "attached scsi removable disk"